# How to prove that if $A$ is a square matrix on $\mathbb{R}$, $A$ is nilpotent, then trace($A$)=0

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant, trace, characteristic-polynomial

I need some help, I need to prove the following:
Let $A$ be a square matrix on $\mathbb{R}$, if $A$ is nilpotent then Trace($A$)=0

I have seen some results for complex entries of the matrix, but what happens with real entries?

I write this because it has been difficult to understand the other answers some people have  written on this website, thanks!

Comment: Probably duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1220470/trace-of-a-nilpotent-matrix-is-zero

Answer (score 2):

Observe that $A\in M(n,\mathbb R)\subset M(n,\mathbb C)$
So trace of $A$ remains the same whether we view it as an element of $M(n,\mathbb R)$  or of $M(n,\mathbb C)$.
Lets us see $A$ as a matrix from $M(n,\mathbb C)$.Then 
[Trace of a matrix is sum of all the eigenvalues of the matrix taken with multiplicity .](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/546167/779382) (all the n eigenvalues of A)

Eigenvalues of nilpotent matrices are zero.(why?)

> $A$ is a nilpotent matrix that is $\exists m>0$ such that $A^m=0$.
>   If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ then there is a vector $v \not = 0$ such that 
>   $$A(v)=\lambda v \implies A^m(v)=\lambda^mv=0 \implies \lambda=0$$ 
>   So all Eigenvalues are zero.